# Are there any solutions to the congruence $3x = 1 \mod 9$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Are there any solutions to the congruence $$3x=1 \mod 9$$?
If so, what are they? If not, why not?

I cannot understand how to proceed through this. It would be helpful if someone could provide a step-by-step guide to the answer.

Thank you.

Comment: This means $3x = 1+9k$ for some integers $x$ and $k$.  Can you see that there is no solution?

Comment: write out each of x=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8. That's it

Comment: If $2$ numbers have the same remainder mod $9$, they do in mod $3$ as well.

Comment: If $9|3x-1$, then $3|3x-1$, so $3|-1$, which is a contradiction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We want $3x\equiv 1\pmod{9}$. This means that $3x=9k+1$ for some integer $k$. However, we can take both sides modulo $3$ to get $3k\pmod{3}=9k+1\pmod{3}\rightarrow 0=1\pmod{3}$, which is obviously not true, thus there are no solutions.

It is also easy to show that $nx\equiv 1\pmod{m}$ has no solutions if $m$ is a multiple of $n$, and they are both not equal to $1$ using the above technique.

Answer (score 0):

We write as true

$\tag 1 3 \times 3 \equiv 0 \pmod9$

If $ab = 1 \pmod9$ then

$\tag 2 3(ab) = 3 \pmod9$

By the rules of algebra/arithmetic, neither $a$ nor $b$ can be equal to $3$. Put another way, don't bother trying to find the inverse of a [zero divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_divisor) in a $\text{modulo-}(n)$ ring.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, $3x\equiv1\pmod{9}$ is the same as $9\mid 3x-1$, or $3x-1=9y$ for some integers $x,y$. If we write this as $$3x-9y=1 \iff 3(x-3y)=1,$$ we see that this cannot be true: the left hand side is a multiple of 3 while 1 is not.